# How to do a pass/continue in .map method for Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

So basically say I have a class:

```
class Book {
  late String title;
  late int publishYear;

  Book({required this.title, required this.publishYear});

  factory Book.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Book(
      title: json['title'],
      publishYear: json['published'],
    );
  }
}
```

Now say I want to filter a list of `Books` by their publish year like so:

```
void filterByPublishYear() {
  List response = responseData; // API Response

  List<Book> books = response.map((e) {
    Book book = Book.fromJson(e);
    if (book.publishYear > 2000) {
      return book;
    }
  }).toList();
}
```

The `.map()` method has an error because it doesn't always return something:

> A value of type 'List<Book?>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.
> Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List'.

I don't want to set the List to type `Book?` neither because, well, they're not supposed to be null ever.

How could I make this work? Is there a way to do a `continue` or a `pass` for `.map()` in dart that could make this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't any way to `pass` or `continue` from within the callback of a `map` function. A few alternative ways to approach would be to use a combination of `map` and `where` as h8moss points out. Or alternatively you achieve the same result using `fold`:

```dart
List<Book> books = response.fold<List<Book>>([], (prev, element) {
  Book book = Book.fromJson(element);
  if (book.publishYear > 2000) {
    prev.add(book);
  }
  return prev;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like what you want is a `where` method:

```
List<Book> books = [
    Book(title: "Harry Potter", publishYear: 1997),
    Book(title: "Diary of a Wimpy Kid", publishYear: 2007),
  ];

  books = books.where((e) => e.publishYear > 2000).toList()
```

The where method takes a function like `map`, but it returns a bool, if the bool is true, it keeps the item, if it's false, it drops it from the list.

Comment: I edited the question. The scenario is a little different. I have to convert an API response into a Books object prior to checking. I was hopping to not have to use ``.where()`` but rather simply do the entire logic in one go. Is that possible?

Comment: @darkstar `responseData.map(Book.fromJson).where((book) => book.publishYear > 2000).toList()`